# css div overflow property usage

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am using bootstrap with angular and I have the foll. code in my component.html file.
The below 2 DIV is only occupying col-sm-6, so the other half of div is empty. Now i want to add another table in this empty space and that occupies both the DIV's.
When I try to add  on the 1st set of div then the new table occupies only in the 1st div and pushes the 2nd div until the length of the table. If i add

then the 1st div right side is empty and the table occupies just from the 2nd div start and goes until the length of the new table. So I tried to add 
overflow: visible; to the 1st Div class="row" but it didnt work. What is the best way to achieve the same?

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-2"></div>
<div class="col-sm-3" style="text-align:center; padding-top: 5px;">
    <table class="col-sm-12">
        <tr>
            <td colspan="12" class="labelStyle" style="text-align: center;background-color:#f4f4f4">
                BMI Chart
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr *ngFor="let item of lkBmiChartList;">
            <td colspan="8" class="labelStyle">{{item.code}}</td>
            <td colspan="4" class="labelStyle">{{item.value}}</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-1"></div>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-3" style="text-align:center; padding-top: 5px;padding-left: 3px;padding-right: 3px;">
    <table class="col-sm-12">......</table>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2" style="text-align:center; padding-top: 5px;padding-left: 3px;padding-right: 3px;">
        <table class="col-sm-12">...</table>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-1" style="text-align:center; padding-top: 5px;padding-left: 3px;padding-right: 3px;">
        <table class="col-sm-12">...</table>
    </div>
</div>
```

I do not want to use scroll bars or anything. The table should occupy the right of both the div and not specific to any row.

Comment: If i correctly understanded try adding a parent row that contains a col-sm-6 div (with your two row inside(change the total column occupied by children to 12)) and another col-sm-6 div with table inside

Comment: Anyway i suggest you to put your <table class="col-sm-12"> inside a row and not inside another col (check bootstrap doc on nesting https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.4/css/#grid-nesting )